# Non-Virtual Interface - how to invoke the correct virtual function

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, non-virtual-interface

I have a hierarchy that looks something like this:

```
class Base
{
public:
    void Execute();
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
private:
    virtual void exec_();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
   //DoSomething is implementation specific for classes Derived from Base
   void DoSomething();

private:
    void exec_();
};

void Base::Execute()
{
    // do some work 
    exec_();  //work specific for derived impl
    // do some other work
}

void Derived::DoSomething()
{
   //impl dependent so it can only be virtual in Base
}


int main()
{
  Derived d;
  Base& b = d;

  b.Execute();  //linker error cause Derived has no Execute() function??

}
```

So the question is how do I call Execute() using this pattern when I create a derived using my Base class.  In my case I do not want to create Derived directly, as I have multiple classes derived from Base and depending on some condition I have to pick a different derived class.

can anyone help?

Comment: Someone please edit the tag wiki for nvi, thanks.

Comment: @Konrad: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface

Comment: Is this supposed to be a complete code sample? If so, linker errors are from missing implementations of Base::exec_() and Derived::DoSomething().

Comment: @CWan, was a mistake... I fixed it now

Comment: [non-virtual-interface] already has a few questions. [nvi] is ambiguous at best IMO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
class Base
{
public:
    void Execute();
private:
    virtual void exec_() {}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    void exec_() {}
};

void Base::Execute()
{
    // do some work 
    exec_();  //work specific for derived impl
    // do some other work
}

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base& b = d;

    b.Execute();
}
```

compiles, links, and runs for me.

Comment: but DoSomething is important though, not sure if you left it out for brevity or because it's wrong that's there?

Comment: I hadn't seen the implementation of `Base::Execute`. +1 to you, the problem is even more trivial than I thought.

Comment: @Tony: `DoSomething` isn't relevant to your problem since it doesn't follow the NVI principle at all.

Comment: @Tony: As far as I can see, it's not used in the example, so I cut it out. But the code still links even if you put it back in (provided you also put in an implementation).

Comment: So, why do you include <iostream>?

Comment: @Tony: Try to copy and paste the exact solution from the answer into a single file, it should work.

Comment: @Cwan: Good catch. It's part of my test cpp file, and I didn't remove it.

Comment: @Tony: If this doesn't compile for you, your compiler is so seriously broken, I doubt you can do anything useful with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably also make exec_() pure virtual in your base class.  You then also need to implement it in your derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a function definition for exec_() function.